# ignore Certificate Error (Alternative Names)

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, webrequest

im doing a WebRequest on webservice.domain.com in an console application:

```
WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url_web);
        WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

and i get an exeption every time the WebRequest is called:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

The Destinationserver is secured by a certificate, bound to mail.domain.com, alternative names are webservice.domain.com and some other subdomains.

Already tried

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });



        WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url_web);
        WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

without success.

"Normal" certificates, wildcard or standard work without any problems.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Yay sorry. Thanks for the advice Andreas!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
webRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

Comment: I tried to put it in front of the webrequest, but now it asks me to declare the local var before using it. I really dont know HOW i should declare the webRequest?

Comment: This needs to be after you declare your web request object

Comment: I did: "System.Net.WebRequest" holds no definition for "ServerCertificateValidationCallback". i hope this is translated right :)

Comment: For the Moment i found a way to do it: i removed the: WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse(); because i dont need a response! But its not the "solution" i want....